# Android. ScrollView is shown beneath of previous layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two linear layouts and ScrollView in my layout.
I add a few views to ScrollView programmatically.
All is okay, if views in ScrollView are inside of the screen.
But if more views in ScrollView, the first view of scrollview
is under layout2 and partly invisible.
I tryed relative layout. But the same performance.
Of course I'd like to see top element of scrollview without truncating.

[image]

My XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/backNormal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/backNormal"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageDriverWaitingBack"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:gravity="left"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDriverWaitingTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Title"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text1"
            android:layout_weight="2.13"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/backDark2"
        />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/backNormal"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/dButtonWaitMinus"
            android:text='-'
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/button_style_normal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dTextWaitDist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Distance"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text1"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/dButtonWaitPlus"
            android:text='+'
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/button_style_normal"
            />

</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

        >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/driverWaitList"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/backNormal"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas please! Thanks!

Comment: post your layout xml and code as well.

Comment: U can use list view instead of `scroll view`

Comment: Try to set some some margins between the LinearLayout and your ScrollView. But it seems you can use ListView in this case since your items have the same structure. You can add in items by update the item list and notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter.

Comment: Hmm. ListView? I doubt. Linear or relative layout would be good.

Comment: Why don't you use LIstView instead of scroll views because your scroll view has same child views with different data,